# How can I retrieve the first word of the output of a command in Bash?

Tags: bash

I have a command, for example: `echo "word1 word2"`. I want to put a pipe (`|`) and get "word1" from the command.

```
echo "word1 word2" | ....
```

What should I put after the pipe?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

[AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) is a good option if you have to deal with trailing whitespace because it'll take care of it for you:

```
echo "   word1  word2 " | awk '{print $1;}' # Prints "word1"
```

[cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix)) won't take care of this though:

```
echo "  word1  word2 " | cut -f 1 -d " " # Prints nothing/whitespace
```

'cut' here prints nothing/whitespace, because the first thing before a space was another space.

Comment: Is the semi-colon necessary?

Comment: It should be "leading" whitespace (at the begin of the string), not "trailing".

Comment: @AlicePurcell I tried it without ; and it worked for me (MBP 10.14.2)

Comment: This doesn't work if the string is e.g. "firstWord, secondWord" as that awk command delimiters by space

Comment: @RogerOba That wasn't the OP's question, but you can use `-F","` to override the default field separator (a space) with a comma.

Answer (score 83):

There isn't any need to use external commands. Bash itself can do the job. Assuming "word1 word2" you got from somewhere and stored in a variable, for example,

```
$ string="word1 word2"
$ set -- $string
$ echo $1
word1
$ echo $2
word2
```

Now you can assign `$1`, `$2`, etc. to another variable if you like.

Comment: +1 for using only shell built-ins and `stdin`. @Matt M. `--` means `stdin`, so `$string` is being passed in as `stdin`. `stdin` is whitespace-separated into arguments `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc. - just like when a Bash program evaluates arguments (e.g. check `$1`, `$2`, etc.), this approach takes advantage of the shell's tendency to split the `stdin` into arguments automatically, removing the need for `awk` or `cut`.

Comment: @CalebXu Not stdin, `set` sets the shell arguments.

Comment: `word1=$(IFS=" " ; set -- $string ; echo $1)` Set IFS to correctly recognize the space between the words.  Wrap in parentheses to avoid clobbering the original content of $1.

Comment: This is broken as it's subject to pathname expansion. Try it with `string="*"`. Surprise.

Comment: Good answer, because this is valid not only for Bash, but even for the traditional Bourne shell as well.

Comment: It can be even simpler: `arr=(word1 word2)` and `echo $arr` (in the `echo` it "defaults" to the first element). Or if the string is already in a variable: `string="word1 word2"`, `arr=($string)`, and `echo $arr`

Answer (score 38):

I think one efficient way is the use of Bash arrays:

```
array=( $string ) # Do not use quotes in order to allow word expansion
echo ${array[0]}  # You can retrieve any word. Index runs from 0 to length-1
```

Also, you can directly read arrays in a pipe-line:

```
echo "word1 word2" | while read -a array; do echo "${array[0]}" ; done
```

Comment: `echo "  word1  word2  " | { read -a array ; echo ${array[0]} ; }`

Comment: This is broken as it's subject to pathname expansion. Try it with `string="*"`. Surprise.

Comment: Use the `while` syntax to retrieve every first word at each line.
Otherwise, use Boontawee Home approach.
Also, please note that `echo "${array[0]}"` has been quoted to prevent expansion as noticed by gniourf-gniourf.

Comment: If you try to access an index of array which is greater than the number of words, then you won't get an error. You will just get an empty line

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: It isn't broken if the input is restricted.

Answer (score 34):

```
echo "word1 word2 word3" | { read first rest ; echo $first ; }
```

This has the advantage that is not using external commands and leaves the $1, $2, etc. variables intact.

Comment: Leaving the variables `$1, $2, …` intact is an extremely useful feature for script writing!

Comment: much better than the accepted answer, since this also works for any type of whitespace

Answer (score 20):

### Using shell parameter expansion `%% *`

Here is another solution using [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). It takes care of multiple spaces after the first word. Handling spaces in front of the first word requires one additional expansion.

```
string='word1    word2'
echo ${string%% *}
word1

string='word1    word2      '
echo ${string%% *}
word1
```

#### Explanation

The `%%` signifies *deleting* the longest possible match of  `*` (a space followed by any number of whatever other characters) in the *trailing* part of `string`.

Answer (score 17):

You could try AWK:

```
echo "word1 word2" | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

With AWK it is really easy to pick any word you like (`$1`, `$2`, etc.).

Answer (score 16):

If you are sure there are no leading spaces, you can use Bash parameter substitution:

```
$ string="word1  word2"
$ echo ${string/%\ */}
word1
```

Watch out for escaping the single space. See [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) for more examples of substitution patterns. If you have Bash > 3.0, you could also use regular expression matching to cope with leading spaces - see [here](http://grulos.blogspot.co.uk/2006/02/bashrematch-regular-expressions.html):

```
$ string="  word1   word2"
$ [[ ${string} =~ \ *([^\ ]*) ]]
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
word1
```

Answer (score 14):

I wondered how several of the top answers measured up in terms of speed. I tested the following:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440521/1241736) @mattbh's

```
echo "..." | awk '{print $1;}'
```

[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440602/1241736) @ghostdog74's

```
string="..."; set -- $string; echo $1
```

[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440414/how-to-retrieve-the-first-word-of-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash#comment58766363_30012692) @boontawee-home's

```
echo "..." | { read -a array ; echo ${array[0]} ; }
```

and [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440414/how-to-retrieve-the-first-word-of-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash#comment58766406_23750121) @boontawee-home's

```
echo "..." | { read first _ ; echo $first ; }
```

I measured them with Python's `timeit` in a Bash script in a zsh terminal on macOS, using a test string with 215 5-letter words. I did each measurement five times (the results were all for 100 loops, best of 3), and averaged the results:

```
Method       Time
--------------------------------
1. awk       9.2 ms
2. set       11.6 ms (1.26 * "1")
3. read -a   11.7 ms (1.27 * "1")
4. read      13.6 ms (1.48 * "1")
```

Comment: Weird that you could measure 3 in dash, since dash doesn't support arrays (`read -a` is invalid in dash).

Comment: Yeah that is weird. I ruled that one out, did the speed tests, then thought "why'd I leave that one out" and added it in. Removing it now, and I may rerun things later to make sure I didn't have some mistake

Answer (score 8):

```
echo "word1 word2" | cut -f 1 -d " "
```

[cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix)) cuts the first field (`-f 1`) from a list of fields delimited by the string " " (`-d " "`).

Comment: that's one way, but your cut statement won't distinguish multiple spaces in between words if he wants to get word2 later on

Comment: yep, the awk solution is the better one.

Answer (score 6):

`read` is your friend:

- If string is in a variable:

  ```
  string="word1 word2"
  read -r first _ <<< "$string"
  printf '%s\n' "$first"
  ```
- If you're working in a pipe: first case: you only want the first word of the first line:

  ```
  printf '%s\n' "word1 word2" "line2" | { read -r first _; printf '%s\n' "$first"; }
  ```

  second case: you want the first word of each line:

  ```
  printf '%s\n' "word1 word2" "worda wordb" | while read -r first _; do printf '%s\n' "$first"; done
  ```

These work if there are leading spaces:

```
printf '%s\n' "   word1 word2" | { read -r first _; printf '%s\n' "$first"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

As Perl incorporates AWK's functionality, this can be solved with Perl too:

```
echo " word1 word2" | perl -lane 'print $F[0]'
```

Comment: That actually works, even with the leading zero, but an explanation would be in order. Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41869233/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind installing a new command, I would recommend [choose](https://github.com/theryangeary/choose)

It has the simplest and most intuitive interface of all alternatives:

```bash
echo "word1 word2" | choose 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working with an embedded device which had neither Perl, AWK or Python and did it with [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) instead. It supports multiple spaces before the first word (which the `cut` and `bash` solutions did not handle).

```
VARIABLE="  first_word_with_spaces_before_and_after  another_word  "
echo $VARIABLE | sed 's/ *\([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

This was very useful when grepping `ps` for process IDs since the other solutions here using only Bash was not able to remove the first spaces which `ps` uses to align.