# Remove the first word in a text stream

Tags: bash, sed, awk, cat

How would I remove the first word from each line of text in a stream?

For example,

```
$ cat myfile
some text 1
some text 2
some text 3
```

I want:

```
$ cat myfile | magiccommand
text 1
text 2
text 3
```

How would I go about this using Bash?  I could use `awk '{print $2 $3 $4 $5 ....}'`, but that's messy and would result in extra spaces for all null arguments.  I was thinking that sed might be able to do this, but I could not find any examples of this.

Comment: Somewhat related: *[How can I retrieve the first word of the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440414)*

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Based on your example text,

```
cut -d' ' -f2- yourFile
```

should do the job.

Comment: Caution: I tried using this to remove the indexing on the output of `history` and it doesn't work at the start of history due to the spaces before the smaller numbers acting as delimiters.

Comment: @JasonDoucette different input formats may need different solutions

Answer (score 13):

That should work:

```
$ cat test.txt
some text 1
some text 2
some text 3

$ sed -e 's/^\w*\ *//' test.txt
text 1
text 2
text 3
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is a solution using `awk`

```
awk '{$1= ""; print $0}' yourfile
```

Comment: This will leave a space in the beginning of each line

Comment: simple and excellent solution, I don't mind the extra whitespace :D

Answer (score 6):

Run this:

```
sed "s/^some\s//g" myfile
```

You even don't need to use a pipe.

Comment: You can't even use a pipe.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the first word, until space no matter how many spaces exist, use: `sed 's/[^ ]* *//'`

Example:

```
$ cat myfile 
some text 1
some  text 2
some     text 3

$ cat myfile | sed 's/[^ ]* *//'
text 1
text 2
text 3
```