# How can I remove the first part of a string in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

This code will give the first part, but how can I remove it and get the whole string without the first part?

```
echo "first second third etc"|cut -d " " -f1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Remove First Word in text stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814205/remove-first-word-in-text-stream)*

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should have a look at `info cut`, which will explain what `f1` means.

Actually we just need fields after(and) the second field. `-f` tells the command to search by field, and `2-` means the second and following fields.

```
echo "first second third etc" | cut -d " " -f2-
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use [substring removal](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for that. There isn't any need for external tools:

```
$ foo="a b c d"
$ echo "${foo#* }"
b c d
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do:

```
echo "first second third etc" | cut -d " " -f2-
>> second third etc
```

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this:

```
echo "first second third etc" | cut -d " " -f2-
```

It's explained in

```
 man cut | less +/N-
```

> N-     from N'th byte, character or field, to end of line

As far of you have the [Bash tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash), you can use [Bash parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) like this:

```
x="first second third etc"
echo ${x#* }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  echo "first second third etc" | cut -d " " -f2-
```