# Get first word of string with sed

Tags: bash, sed

How can i cut with sed the following property to have only `MAC`?

```
MAC evbyminsd58df
```

I did this but it works in the other side:

```
sed -e 's/^.\{1\}//'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve the first word of the output of a command in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440414/how-to-retrieve-the-first-word-of-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)

Comment: If what you really want is to remove the first word of command output, then definitely go to the above link. The answers are comprehensive.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just remove everything from the space:

```
$ echo "MAC evbyminsd58df" | sed 's/ .*//'
MAC
```

As you mention cut, you can use `cut` selecting the first field based on space as separator:

```
$ echo "MAC evbyminsd58df" | cut -d" " -f1
MAC
```

With pure Bash, either of these:

```
$ read a _ <<< "MAC evbyminsd58df"
$ echo "$a"
MAC

$ echo "MAC evbyminsd58df" | { read a _; echo "$a"; }
MAC
```

Comment: `man read` does not show any mention of `_` that you used in `read a _ <<< "MAC evbyminsd58df"`. How did you learn about this ? Where can I see the explanation of `_` used in `read` command ?

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut `_` is just any name. We tend to use this name to show that it is a throw away variable that is not going to be used any more. Same as saying `read a b <<< "MAC evbyminsd58df"`

Comment: Why did I even search for this. You are so right, and I feel like I'm not. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

with **`cut`** (space as delimiter, select first field):

```
echo "MAC evbyminsd58df" | cut -d " " -f 1
```

with **`awk`** (select print first field, space is default delimiter):

```
echo "MAC evbyminsd58df" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use grep like below,

```
grep -o '^[^ ]\+' file
```

OR

```
grep -o '^[^[:space:]]\+' file
```

`^` Asserts that we are at the start. `[^[:space:]]` Negated POSIX character class which matches any character but not of a space , zero or more times.